# How not to lose columns in a result of a pixel extraction, if some column is equal to zero?

Tags: r, extract, pixel

I have reclassified some classes of a raster into two classes (natural and anthropic) and I have to extract the pixel proportion of each class for some study areas that I have. However, there is a time when, among all my study areas, one of them did not have values ​​for the anthropic class (it's ok, this is normal), but, the code I am using excludes this column and I don' t want to exclude it, because I will bind (rbind) with results from my others study areas, and they should have the same length ( columns number).

```
#The data raster
map<-raster("prodes.tif")
```

## raster structure

[image]

```
study_area<- readOGR("study_area)
```

## Shapefile structure

[image]

```
 #extract the pixels values to my study area
 ( extrc <- extract(map, study_area) )

      #here calculted the prportion of each class (anthropic and natural)
      ( class.prop <- lapply(extrc,FUN = function(x) { prop.table(table(x))}))

  # now I creted use this function to tranform  "class.prop" in a Data Frame
   rbind.fil <- function(x) {
   nam <- sapply(x, names)
   unam <- unique(unlist(nam))
   len <- sapply(x, length)
   out <- vector("list", length(len))
   for (s in seq_along(len)) {
   out[[s]] <- unname(x[[s]])[match(unam, nam[[s]])]
    }
   setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, out), stringsAsFactors=FALSE), unam)
  }

  ( p.prop <- rbind.fil(class.prop) )



      # I inser a new IDcolumn 
      p.prop$ID<-seq_along(p.prop[,1])

      #change the classes names
      names(p.prop)[names(p.prop) == '0'] <- 'anthropic'
      names(p.prop)[names(p.prop) == '1'] <- 'Natural'
```

## It's missing the anthropic column

[image]

```
      #Do the same to my study area shape 
      study-area$ID<- 1:length(study-area)


      freq <- merge(study-area, p.prop) #add to polygons

      frequenc<-as.data.frame(freq) # transfor to data frame



      results <- rbind(results, frequenc) #bind with my previous results


      write.table(results, file="resultados.txt", sep="\t", row.names=F) #save as txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm struggling with this - mostly because we don't have your data to work with, or a sample dataset (smaller than 9 billion cells, please), and because we prefer cut-n-paste code and output instead of screenshots.

The fundamental problem is in your `table` call - what is happening is that if the samples are all in the same class the table has length-one and so the other class is missing. What you want perhaps is to change this:

```
> table(c(1,1,1,1))

1 
4
```

to this:

```
> table(factor(c(1,1,1,1),levels=c(0,1)))

0 1 
0 4
```

This will always return a table with the same length as the `levels`, and the `levels` should be all the possible values you care about in the raster.

Having done that your `rbind.fil` function seems to break, but its okay we can do this much easier now that everything we extract is the same size, using `do.call` and `rbind.data.frame` to make a data frame. Wrap that in `setNames` with the corresponding labels for 0 and 1 and its all in one line:

```
> extrc <- extract(map, study_area) 
> class.prop = lapply(extrc, function(x){table(factor(x,levels=c(0,1)))})
```

This is now a list where every element has two values.

```
> p.prop = setNames(
            do.call(
               rbind.data.frame,
               class.prop),
            c("anthropic","natural"))
```

Giving this which you can stick your ID values on easy enough:

```
> head(p.prop)
  anthropic natural
1         0       2
2         0       1
3         0       1
4         0       1
5         0       2
6         0       2
...
14         0       1
15         1       3
16         1       3
17         0       1
```

This is on a test data set I made with a small raster of mostly ones.

Comment: Thank you !! Works great, even without my data, you helped me!
About rbind.fill, you were right, I had some problems, like creating duplicate or triplicate columns; in that case, to fix it, I’ll insert a new code, ( `p.prop<-p.prop[,!duplicated(colnames(p.prop))]`) to eliminate those columns, but now don' t need it any more. So you solved another problem that I had that I didn't mention here, thanks again. And, I increase the prop.table, like this: (`class.prop = lapply(extrc, function(x){prop.table(table(factor(x,levels=c(0,1))))})`) because I want to obtain proportion of each class.